# Fetch fields from database in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

My entity class is like

```
class myData{
    private $id;
    private $dob;

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setDob($dob)
    {
        $this->dob = new \DateTime($dob);
        return $this;
    }

    public function getDob()
    {
        return $this->dob;
    }
}
```

and in my controller file I am accessing the data like below:

```
public function outputAction(){
    $request = $this->get('request');
    $formid = $request->query->get('formid');
    $formData = $em->getRepository('acmedemoBundle:myData')->findById($formid);
}
```

I need to access the Dob field here.
Please suggest how to access.

I am using Symfony 2.4

Comment: `$formData->getDob();` No? But check at first that something was found by id.

Comment: @cherry: Yes, one result was found by id and when using         $formData->getDob(); I get and error "Call to a member function getDob() on a non-object"

Comment: It means nothing was found. Check it by `if (!$formData) echo 'Not found';`

Comment: when I var_dump($formData); or print_r($formData); I am getting the record. But getting the error when I use $formData->getDob(); Also, if (!$formData) echo 'Not found'; does not print anything, which means $formData holds a record. Please suggest.

Comment: What is the classname of the object in record? Does it have field `dob`? Show the full class of entity - in your's you do not have annotation for db and property by itself. `private $id; private $id;` is it a typo?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62564/discussion-between-anand-s-bahuguna-and-cheery).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$formData = $em->getRepository('acmedemoBundle:myData')->findOneById($formid);
$formData->getDob()
```

Or

```
$formData = $em->getRepository('acmedemoBundle:myData')->findById($formid);
$formData[0]->getDob()
```

Answer (score 0):

given you print_r of the $formData I would say try

```
$formData[0]->getDob();
```